# Run two projects in single launch.json

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have two projects with common root opened in visual code. First is .net core webapi. Second is frontend on react/redux etc. Now when I want to run application I need to manually from console run 'npm start' and then run webapi from visual code. How can I achieve this with configuration of vs code?

At then end I want that after clicking debug I will have recompiled and deployed webapi and rebuild and same with frontend app. Then open browser in desired page.

There is an idea that I can run some script that would handle that, but I would prefer do it with pure vs code configuration.

I think that I need to modify my launch.json file. Don't know how though.
This is launch.json https://pastebin.com/9a66n3Rx

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/webapi.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
```

Frontend app is in "${workspaceFolder}/client" folder

Comment: writing a script seems like the easiest and smartest approach

Comment: Ok, I couldn't belive that it hasn't been natively resolved in vs code. Too bad

Comment: it might be. even if it was, I would still write a script.